# BaseAdaptor usage for Dynamic Content

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

Im currently doing some android developer that lists items in a `ListView`, we have created a `WebView` that add's a JavaScript interface to our page and our page sends information via the JavaScript interface. this all works as expected, so we set up a class called `HangoutManager` that extends a `BaseAdapter`, we have implemented several methods in there such as `add`/`remove` and `exists`.

This all works fine and now were at the point where need to use the `BaseAdapter` to update the `ViewList` when there changes to the Array Stack.

We can't seem to get it too work, the `getView()` function never get's called to generate an item. here is some code.

### onCreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //Call parent to construct the Activity
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Create Instance of HangoutManager, must be called here
    HangoutManagerList = HangoutManager.Instance(this);

    //Set the content view to the main ListView
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //instantiate the WebView
    CanopyWebView = new CanopyWebView(this);

   setListAdapter(HangoutManagerList);
}
```

### HangoutManager

```
public class HangoutManager extends BaseAdapter
{
    public static HangoutManager _Instance;
    private ArrayList<JSONObject> DataSet = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

    protected LayoutInflater Inflater;

    public static HangoutManager Instance(Context context)
    {
        if(_Instance == null)
        {
            _Instance = new HangoutManager(context);
            Log.v("HangoutManager", "Instance Created");
        }

        return _Instance;
    }

    public HangoutManager(Context context)
    {
        this.Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);       
    }

    public boolean remove(String id)
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i=0 ; i< DataSet.size() ; i++ )
            {

                if(DataSet.get(i).getString("id").equals(id))
                {
                    DataSet.remove(i);
                    Log.v("HangoutManager", "hangout Removed");
                    return true;
                }   
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("HangoutManager::exists",e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean add(String hangout)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject HangoutJson = new JSONObject(hangout);
            if(this.exists(HangoutJson.getString("id")))
            {
                this.remove(HangoutJson.getString("id"));
            }

            DataSet.add(HangoutJson);
            Log.v("HangoutManager", "hangout Added");

                    notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("HangoutManager",e.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }


    public boolean exists(String id)
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i=0 ; i< DataSet.size() ; i++ )
            {
                if(DataSet.get(i).getString("id").equals(id))
                {
                    Log.v("HangoutManager", "hangoutExists: " + id);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("HangoutManager::exists",e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return DataSet.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return DataSet.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {

        if(view == null)
        {
            view = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, viewGroup, false);
        }

        //Get the JSONObject for the Item
        JSONObject entity = DataSet.get(position);

        //Set the JSONObject as the tag for the row
        view.setTag(entity);

        //return the view to be drawn
        return view;
    }
}
```

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:id="@android:id/list">
</ListView>
```

### item1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#FF000000"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### StackTrace (not error stacktrace)

- http://pastebin.com/1ftkiLBF

The section about is where we attempt to break but it never breaks at that point, am we doing something wrong ?

### Update

The application seems to crash sometime during the `notifyDataSetChanged()` calls.

Comment: I don't see a setContentView() in your onCreate. I suppose you removed it for clarity. Could you add it back? and also paste your layout?

Comment: updated with `main.xml`, and also added back the method call for the view

Comment: the application crashes sometime during the `notifyDataSetChanged()` call.

Comment: If the application crashes you might also want to provide us the stacktrace ;)

Comment: This seems ok. You said that you did put a breakpoint in getView and it was never called? You actually don't do anything in getView other than setTag(), I suppose you removed also for clarity. Do you mind adding back the code updating the view?

Comment: I assign a break-=point at the first line of `getView()`, which it never breaks, i have not built that function yet because it's not running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call the inflater like this.
Use the following syntax to get an Inflater to use from your getView()

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Also about the stacktrace, it looks like your JS interface callbacks are executed in background. You *cannot* modify the data collection binded to the `ListView` nor call `updateNotifyDataset()` from a background thread.

But you can ask the UIThread to do it for you by calling your add method like this:

```
yourActivityInstance.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        yourAdapterInstance.add(newHangout);
}});
```

Comment: pcans, your the man, thank you, this is my first time developing in Android and Java, I assumed the web request would run on the same thread that initiated them.